# display custom attributes on Virtuemart browse page

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I need the browse page to show quantity box, custom attributes, and Add to Cart button all together.

It doesn't show it at all. Only when you  go to the product page, you can see them.

Any solutions?

Thanks, Ahmed.

Answer (score 0):

Ahmed, you'll have to modify the template directly to do something like that. VM uses a large number of template files written in PHP. If you're using the `default` template, you can find them here:

```
components/com_virtuemart/themes/default/templates/
```

From there, it takes a little looking around to figure out exactly which template you need to edit. If you need to edit a browse template, my recommendation is go to your **VirtueMart Administration** in Joomla backend and look at **Admin | Configuration | Site | Layout** to get an idea of which files you're using. It will probably say "Default" in the dropdown, with a **Configuration** link directly below. Click that link and look at the very first item, **Product List Style**. From the description of your layout desires, you might be using **Flat Product List**.

The main file for editing that layout is:

```
components/com_virtuemart/themes/default/templates/browse/includes/browse_listtable.tpl.php
```

If you're a programmer, you should be able to look thru the code and correctly guess which code elements are being used to display VM product details. If you're not a programmer, you can still fake it by commenting out sections to see what "goes away" on the actual product page. Use what you learn to strip out useful code and move it around.

Another useful file to pull VM product code from is:

```
components/com_virtuemart/themes/default/templates/product_details/flypage.tpl.php
```

This is the actual product view (unless it's been changed in VM config), and contains pretty much all the common code elements that extract product details. You should be able to lift some of that code and place it where it needs to go in other forms.

Good luck with all of this. I find VM coding painful, and community support in the VM forums can be... sparse...